# Square normalized Splines

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spline

[The M-Spline basis functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-spline) have the neat property that they integrate to one
$$
\int M_i(x, k, t) dx = 1
$$
and therefore any M-Spline
$$
\int \sum_i a_i M_i(x,k,t) dx = 1
$$
if the coefficients $a_i$ sum to one. I am wondering if there is a square normalized version of this, so a version where we get:
$$
\int \left(\sum_i a_i M^*_i(x,k,t)\right)^2 dx = 1
$$
We could of course just use any normal M or B spline, square and normalize it, but is there some work done on this and are there some nice recurrence relations known?